# How to write a sql query for getting Sum from two different Table in a single query Having two column for that

Tags: sql

I am trying to getting sum value from two different table in a single SQL query which have two column for that.
Example is that.

> Please provide a SQL query which have give me a result which shows Dealer Name, and Sum amount of Billing (which is to be sum from 1. Billing Table) and Sum amount of Outstanding (Which is to be sum from 2. Outstanding Table)

[image]

Comment: Please provide example data for the two tables and the results you'd want from that example data; [mre]

Comment: You'll need to JOIN the two tables, and then GROUP BY the key columns.

Comment: 1.Billing Table  
  
Dealer Name Billing Amount 
Ramesh 1000 
Suresh 1000 
Ramesh 1000 
Suresh 2500 
  
  
2.Outstanding Table  
  
Dealer Name Outstanding Amount 
Ramesh 200 
Suresh 300 
Ramesh 400 
Suresh 100 
  
  
3.Desired Result  
Dealer Name Net Billing Amount Net Outstanding Amount
Ramesh 2000 600
Suresh 3500 400

Comment: Dear sir, I am using join bt not getting true answer, My sql query is   :  SELECT Daybook.Particulars, SUM(DISTINCT Daybook.DebitAmount) AS DrTotal,SUM(DISTINCT CommonSalesReport.Value) AS VALUETotal  FROM Daybook LEFT JOIN CommonSalesReport ON Daybook.Particulars=CommonSalesReport.DealerName GROUP BY Daybook.Particulars

Comment: Don't post images of sample data. Use [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post) instead.

Comment: Don't post code, data or anything similar in comments. use [edit] link under your question instead.

Comment: Dear mam please help me to write, how to add join with ""with" Clause in sql statement."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with t as (select dealer-name, sum(OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT) as OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT  from outstanding
    group by dealer-name)
select b. dealer-name, sum(b. billing-amount),t. OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT from billing b, t
    where b. dealer-name = t. dealer-name
    group by b. dealer-name, t. OUTSTANDING_AMOUNT
    order by b. dealer-name asc;
```

Comment: I am very thankful for that its resolve my query, May you alter this query , adding a join in that. Please solve this sir adding join so that i generate report as my requirement.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).